# Extremising $\int_0^1 f(x) f(1-x) \ \mathrm{d}x$ subject to length of $f$ and endpoints

Tags: calculus, optimization, calculus-of-variations, constraints, euler-lagrange-equation

I have recently learnt some Calculus of Variations and was trying to apply this to a question I made:

Over all functions $f: [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $f(0) = f(1) = 0$ with fixed curve length $\ell \geq 1$ (i.e. $\int_0^1 \sqrt{1 + (f'(x))^2} \ \mathrm{d}x = \ell$), find $f$ which maximise and minimise
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 f(x) f(1 - x) \ \mathrm{d}x.
\end{align*}

Ordinarily, I would proceed by Lagrange Multipliers and use Euler-Lagrange equations to solve for $f$, but I'm not sure how this would work with $f$ being shifted above. I considered rederiving the Euler-Lagrange equation for this as well, but the fact that it is a shifted argument makes me think this would likely not be nice to work with.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I know very little about calculus of variations, but couldn't you make the integral arbitrarily large and small? Large by choosing a large 'bump' function, symmetric about $x=1/2$, small with a double bump function, antisymmetric about $x=1/2$?

Comment: @achillehui Yeah, I specified $\ell \geq 1$ just so that the function would exist.

Comment: $$ F= \int_0^1 y(x) y(1-x) dx$$

$$ dF = \int_0^1  \left( y+ \epsilon \eta(x) \right) \left[ y(1-x) + \epsilon \eta(1-x) \right] - y(x)y(1-x) dx = \int_0^1 \epsilon \left[ \eta(x)y(1-x)+ y(x) \eta(1-x) \right] + O(\epsilon^2) dx$$

We set the first order variation to zero:

$$ \eta(x) y(1-x) + y(x) \eta(1-x) = 0$$

Comment: We need to find $y$ such the last statement is true for any $\eta$ to my understanding

Comment: @Steven Since the length of the curve is bounded, your bump can't really be too big, it's bounded by $\ell$.

Comment: Do you mean $\ell$ is a fixed number, and you minimize along $f$ with a fixed $\ell$?

Comment: @ArcticChar Yes, I'll edit

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The extended functional reads

$$ J[f]~=~\int_0^1\!\mathrm{d}x\left( f(x)f(1-x)+\lambda \sqrt{1+f^{\prime}(x)^2} \right) -\lambda \ell, $$

where $\lambda$ is a [Lagrange multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier). The EL equation becomes non-local:

$$ 2f(1-x)~=~\lambda\frac{d}{dx}\frac{f^{\prime}(x)}{\sqrt{1+f^{\prime}(x)^2}}.$$